# Gravity on the terraformed moon and its inventions

Tags: gravity, moons, atmosphere, terraforming

[Edited version]

In this long-into-the-future scenario the Moon has been **successfully** terraformed, along with other moons in our solar system. Let's just assume economics, AI and human will have made it possible and the technology to achive **and maintain** atmosphere, an artificial magnetic field and other necessities like cozy temperatures exist, and all had about a thousand years or more to establish. Water from nearby asteriods is not a shocker to anyone anymore but rather on the daily delivery schedule.

People have been born here, they walk around freely, or there exists a neat, little device to make it possible.
The moon has 1/6th of earths gravity and the atmosphere is dense enough to keep things like water in place.

**So now my question evolves around movement in low gravity in this scenario:**

- How does the 1/6th-gravity work out in daily life, how would people commute? Apart from walking and jumping like on clouds.
- And what inventions could evolve to improve travel and transport?

My ideas so far circle around wing-like gliders to run, jump and glide with, as well as something like one-person quadrocopters, and high-speed train tracks.

Comment: You're asking too many questions all at once, and that's the sort of thing that gets your post flagged as too broad and put on hold. Focus! You're also combining things with concrete answers ("is mooncat's terminal velocity terminal?") and open-ended opinion-based things ("What other gadgets could you imagine would exist?"), the latter of which don't generally work very well here.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is dedicated to providing detailed answers to specific questions you have while developing your fictional world. We strongly discourage posts asking multiple questions, commonly putting them on hold to allow the author to narrow the scope. If you haven't already, feel free to take the [tour] and check out our [site culture](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388/6986) to get a better understanding of the site.

Comment: Notice that even with a magnetic field, the atmosphere would slowly leak away due to the lower gravity. The Moon cannot hold gases such as oxygen and nitrogen for long.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input! I'll split up the questions and leave this threat for the possible inventions within low gravity, as the title implicates.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Since the gravity is 1/6-th of that on the earth, running would probably more comfortable using longer jumps. Walking on water would not be possible - since the water experiences the same gravity, the buoyant force would be equally 1/6-th of that on earth (I neglect the surface tension here). Cats could jump from heights 6x higher than on earth.
- If diving is limited by the pressure you experience, you could dive 6x times deeper.
- Settling time of dust is not influenced by air pressure. Mostly by wind and gravity I guess. Same as above, with the same conditions, it could take 6x longer to settle. (I neglect electrostatic charges and everything else.)

All the above answers assume, that you and your cat grew up on earth and you have earth musculatures. If you never had to fight higher gravity, you probably won't have enough musculature to jump 6x higher or dive 6x deeper.

One thing you must consider: air pressure is gonna be 6x lower if the gravity is 6x lower. That's around 0,16 bar. Even on [Himalaya](https://hypertextbook.com/facts/2001/JaredGoldberger.shtml), you have around 30kPa = 0.3bar pressure. If you are not genetically adapted/modified, you won't be able to breath on the moon.

Comment: Please answer only well asked question. Pointing to the tour when you are the first not observing our policies is pointless.

Comment: Nice input, thanks a lot! I am doubtful about the 1/6th lower gravity = 6x higher consequence theory. There will probably be a lot of other factors weighing in. I appreaciate the note about different muscle strength, definitely taking that into consideration.